# Since update to 16.04 LTS - crashes every 10-15 mins

Tags: 16.04, crash

When I first tried Ubuntu, about 6 months ago, I had this similar problem - but not as frequent, and usually if I had too many windows open.  And, over time, it seemed to diminish - in the last month, it seemed to crash infrequently; I'm wondering if some bugs got worked out?

My install crashed and I reinstalled over the weekend and upgraded to 16.04 LTS.  I've been using it about 3 or 4 days now and it freezes up and then reboots every 10 mins or so.  Maybe 20, 30 or even 40 times per day.

Even if I'm only running with a few windows open.

It always freezes up if I move the cursor when (at the same time), a window is opening or expanding.

Is there anything I can do to mitigate this?

Answer (score 1):

I strongly believe the problem would be with the Hardware. If you are using a laptop make sure that temperature is raising up high due to expired thermal paste or fan speed issue. Apart from that either the desktop or laptop kindly check their RAM is working fine without any issues and check with the motherboard issues. To find out if its all because of motherboard or RAM issue, use that Ubuntu installed HDD in other computer or laptop and trying booting it up and check still the issue persists. That will be much easier to troubleshoot these issue in the first place. if it fails we can go ahead with the other steps.

Comment: I've never seen temperature issues that just reboot, usually a hard shutdown or CPU throttling.

Comment: I'm tending to think it is a heat issue - older laptop and it gets very hot.  I have noticed that the wifi stops working as it gets hotter.  Seems that it is better or worse by the week and that the time of reinstall just paralleled by happenstance.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with SAGAR's answer, esp. given the spontaneous reboots.  You can also try running a live Ubuntu session (e.g. on a memory stick) and testing memory.  Press and hold any key while your computer is booting.

Press 'F6', a language menu will pop up, select English and press enter. You will then be presented with the option menu.

You can also install 'stress' to see if your machine fails under load.

Answer (score 0):

That issue continued for about 2 years.  I just updated to 18.04.6 and the problem is gone.  Now I have open 8 or 10 windows and it runs like it is a turbo.  Not sure what the other issue was but it is fixed now.